# Cassandra 3.11.1 GeoSpatial support

Tags: cassandra, geospatial

I'm trying to use GeoSpatial example from Cassandra documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/queriesGeoSpatial.html

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id text PRIMARY KEY,  point 'PointType',  linestring 'LineStringType');
```

I'm getting error:

SyntaxException: Error setting type PointType: Unable to find abstract-type class 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.PointType'

I'm using stack:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you are looking at is for DSE 6.7 which is a commercial product has extended functionality over Cassandra 3.11.1. Cassandra 3.11.1 does not support the `PointType`.

Depending on what you are trying to do you, there are a number of open source projects that support geospatial extensions for Cassandra:

[GeoMesa](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/index.html)

[Elassandra](https://www.elassandra.io/)

Comment: From my experience, the GeoMesa on Cassandra is very heavyweight, and generates a lot of the queries, overloading the cluster.